# How can I delete equal rows in a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a table with some data inserted in it. The issue is that there are many rows that are equal to other rows and I want to delete them leaving just one of those rows. For example:

**Table Person**

```
    name       pet
---------------------------
    Mike       Dog
    Kevin      Dog
    Claudia    Cat
    Mike       Dog
    Mike       Dog
    Kevin      Snake
```

As you can see, we can see multiple times that `Person` named `Mike` has a `Dog`. 
But I would like to see it only once. So the output I'll want after update this table is:

```
    name       pet
---------------------------
    Mike       Dog
    Kevin      Dog
    Claudia    Cat
    Kevin      Snake
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Does table `Person` have an id column?

Comment: yes it does @pilcrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `exists`. In apparent absence of a primary key, [system column `ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) can be used:

```
delete from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.name = t.name and t1.pet = t.pet and t1.ctid > t.ctid
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably to recreate the table:

```
create table temp_t as 
    select distinct name, pet
    from t;

truncate table t;   -- back it up first!

insert into t (name, pet)
    select name, pet
    from temp_t;

create unique index unq_t_name_pet on t(name, pet);
```

The last step is to prevent this problem in the future.